# Sum of diagonal binomial coefficients polynomial

Tags: combinatorics

I'm having trouble evaluating the following sum, for constant $n$ and $-1 \leq x \leq 1$:

$$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty} {n+k \choose k}x^k
$$

I know the series must converge by the ratio test, since:

$$
\lim\limits_{k \to \infty}\left|\frac{{n+k+1 \choose k+1}x^{k+1}}{{n+k \choose k}x^k}\right| = \lim\limits_{k \to \infty}\frac{n+k+1}{k+1}\left|x\right| = \left|x\right| < 1.
$$

However, I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\binom{n+k}{k}&=\frac{(n+k)(n+k-1)\dots (n+1)}{k!}\\
&=(-1)^{k}\frac{(-n-1)(-n-2)\dots(-n-k)}{k!}\\
&=(-1)^k\binom{-n-1}{k}
\end{align}
so the series is the binomial expansion of $(1-x)^{-n-1}$.

Comment: Thanks! I've never seen this trick before but that is so powerful... I thought the answer would end up being through a complicated generating function. Does it matter that in the 1st series k goes to infinity but in the second it is effectively bounded? Or are binomial coefficients consistent even when k exceeds n?

Comment: If $n$ is a nonnegative integer, then for $k>n$ the numerator of $\binom{n}{k}$ would contain a factor $0$ (the factor $n-n$) whereas the denominator $k!$ is nonzero.  Hence the infinite series $\sum_k\binom{n}{k}x^k$ has only finitely many nonzero terms.

Comment: I see. Thanks again for the beautiful solution.